# Should one try an audit reconsideration alone or with a CPA?

Tags: irs, audit

If anyone is following my previous questions, I have a long saga of an audit that has gone foul. I hired a CPA to help me but in 8 months he was unable to get the audit sorted out for me.

The CPA firm has recommended to request an audit reconsideration.

My question is, can one do this on their own (to avoid paying the CPA to do this) or should one use the services of a CPA so they do that best possible job that can be done?

The justification of doing it alone is that aside from being late, the actual reporting of the years in questions are accurate and if one has whatever the IRS is requesting to furnish them with. I.e. proof of reported earned income, ss #'s for family members or whatever else, one ought to be granted the right to submit the proof and the IRS can review it and accept it and reverse the penalties/fines.

What is recommended way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, can one do this on their own (to avoid paying the CPA to do this) or should one use the services of a CPA so they do that best possible job that can be done?

Use a CPA. They know the rules, procedures, timelines, forms, ways to frame things and present them, and properly understand and interpret the responses. Ah, they also know the law. You know nothing of these.